# Squiggly AND double line to highlight errors/warnings in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-formatting

After using the Extensions Bisect feature of VSCode (which is a pretty handy tool imo), I figured out that the extension causing the ugly squiggly AND double line to highlight errors/warnings (shown in picture below) in my code is Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat extension.
Usually the errors/warnings are highlighted by squiggly lines only and I would like to keep it that way. I have tried looking for solutions (editor settings, java settings, etc.) but I couldn't find anything related to it. The closest setting I found was to customize the color of errors/warnings but that wouldn't be helpful in this case.
Does anyone know how to get rid of it? It is annoying the heck out of me. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: screenshot is missing. Also, provide a [mre] including code, platform, version info, and jdk info.